# Python regexes: return a list of words containing a given substring

Tags: python, regex, string

What would be a function `f` based on regexes that, given an input text and a string, returns all the words containing this string in the text. For example:

```
f("This is just a simple text to test some basic things", "si")
```

would return:

```
["simple", "basic"]
```

(because these two words contain the substring `"si"`)

How to do that?

Comment: What if the string has special characters?

Comment: What should it return for "This is a simple basic test of some basic things" or "This is a simple, basic test of some basic things"?

Comment: `filter((lambda word: substring in word), text.split())`?

Comment: Why do you need regexes? `[x for x in words.split() if searched_string in x]` should do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not convinced there isn't a better way to do this than my approach, but something like:

```
import re

def f(s, pat):
    pat = r'(\w*%s\w*)' % pat       # Not thrilled about this line
    return re.findall(pat, s)


print f("This is just a simple text to test some basic things", "si")
```

Works:

```
['simple', 'basic']
```

Answer (score 6):

For something like this i wouldn't use regex, I would use something like this:

```
def f(string, match):
    string_list = string.split()
    match_list = []
    for word in string_list:
        if match in word:
            match_list.append(word)
    return match_list

print f("This is just a simple text to test some basic things", "si")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at a solution.  I split the input string by " ", and then try to match each individual word to the pattern.  If a match is found, the word is added to a result set.

```
import re

def f(str, pat):
    matches = list()
    str_list = str.split(' ');

    for word in str_list:
        regex = r'' + re.escape(word)
        match = re.search(regex, word)
        if match:
            matches.append(word)
    return matches

print f("This is just a simple text to test some basic things", "si")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

def func(s, pat):
    pat = r'\b\S*%s\S*\b' % re.escape(pat) 
    return re.findall(pat, s)


print func("This is just a simple text to test some basic things", "si")
```

You need this .`\b` will take out only words by cutting at word boundary.`\S` will not select any `space`.